Is it okay to ask for Bitcoin in our chatroom?
Suppose someone asks for Bitcoin in our chatroom, for the purpose of testing a Bitcoin checkout application.
We've got a policy about doing that in an answer for compensation, but not one about asking in chat.
I've thought of four general approaches to this:

Remove all requests in chat.
Remove it or don't, use your discretion. (What factors should we weigh?)
Only remove it if someone complains.
Allow all requests in chat.

I'm open to other suggestions, though. Thoughts?

I dunno, it sounds a bit like online panhandling.

I'd opt for "use your discretion". As long as it happens about once per year as now, we don't need a fixed rule. If it happens more often, or in a spammy manner, I might consider suspending the user from chat besides removing it.
